# Row updation in xls through python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xls

I want to increase the row no automatically (Here 0 to 4)  and filled with some value ( here Name). But i am getting only last row values is written in xls.

What i have to make changes so that i will get all row ( 0 to 4 with it's value).

```
import xlwt

row_no=0

def xls_write(row_no):

    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Result")
    Name = "Name is "
    sheet1.write(row_no, 0,Name)

    book.save("C:/Users/nirajk/Desktop/Row_checking.xls")

    print "Current row_no is : " , row_no


xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
row_no+=1
xls_write(row_no)
```

Comment: Each time you call the `xls_write` function, you overwrite the `Row_checking.xls` file with a newly created workbook.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "increase the row no automatically" ?

Comment: @Varun Here automatically means For the Next cell_text/Name(passing as a function argument) it will write in a new row. But also here we don't know adjectlly how many call_text will come,That depend on other calculation,  so for writing  next cell_text/Name in a new row. So i want to increase row by one and write the content in to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do but not familiar with the xlwt library so this should get you in the right direction if it doesn't quite solve it.

**Edit:** Expanded for variable text in each cell

```
import xlwt


def xls_write(text, number_of_rows):
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Result")

    for i in range(number_of_rows):
        sheet1.write(i, 0, text[i])
        print "Current row_no is : ", i
        print "Text is : ", text[i]

    book.save("C:/Users/nirajk/Desktop/Row_checking.xls")

words = ["cat", "dog", "horse", etc]
xls_write(words, len(words))
```

Comment: @ FinlayL Thanks for this information, But here we the number of row ( Fixed row size) , iF the number_of_rows is decide at run time and each row value i have to write in xls, can you please help me on this.      Just take a example def xls_write(number_of_rows, Name): in this case when we get first name we have to write in first row , for second name second row and so on.... ,

Comment: @Niraj Expanded so that you can feed it a list of words to write on each row

Answer (score 0):

To answer this 
i used openpyxl module

```
    import openpyxl

    Scene_Catalogue_file_path = "xls_file_path_and_name.xls"

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Scene_Catalogue_file_path)
    print "All availabe_shhet : ", wb.get_sheet_names()

    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('LVDS Recordings') # parsing only specific sheet Recordings

    print "B1", sheet['B1'].value

    call_no = 1
    while(sheet[str('B'+ str(call_no))].value != None):
        mention_recording = sheet['B' + str(call_no)].value
        Host_Vehicle_static_movie = sheet['C' + str(call_no)].value
        Lighting_Condition_poor_good = sheet['D' + str(call_no)].value
        Length  = sheet['I' + str(call_no)].value
```